# How do I add an image to a comment in Trello?

Tags: images, comments, attachment, trello

I like that I can add images to a card in Trello but I would really like the ability to add an image to a comment in trello (without resorting to a third party embed.ly link).  Has anyone come across a solution?

Comment: This is **not really a duplicate**, because **the answers for the other questions are talking about the description** and not the comments. These have different functionality in Trello. At the moment you can not display images in comments using markdown, while it's possible in the description.

Answer (score 2):

Trello does not support features such attachments and markdown in comments.  You can, however, add a URL to the image in the comment.  It will appear as the full text of the URL, but the UI will automatically add a hyperlink.

**Edit (2017)** Markdown in comments has had limited support for some time.

Comment: This is no longer the case. Trello now supports MarkDown: http://help.trello.com/article/821-using-markdown-in-trello

Comment: @wp78de this is true. Of course, it's been over 4 years...

Comment: @wp78de The image markdown for image in the comments is still not supported. :( So this is still the case, since the OP ( like me ) is asking about the image markdown in the comments, not the description.

Comment: @sr9yar Now Mid-2019, Appears to still be the case.. :(

Comment: @MackieeE ... and I still insert images and videos into my comments as links  :) Serves its purpose from the practical viewpoint

Comment: When this was answered originally, markdown was not supported *at all* in comments.  That said, images specifically are still unsupported in comment markdown.

Comment: 2021 and trello still did not managed to add such functionality. Is there better alternatives than trello? it really sucks